# Android: How to get the right application name?

Tags: android, android-activity, package, launch

Currently I have written a code to load all capable applications which can view images from the phone.

```
public static List<String> getAllCapableForFileViewing (Context context, String mimeType) {
    List<String> packages = new ArrayList<>();
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    sendIntent.setType(mimeType);
    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = context.getPackageManager()
            .queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);

    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfoList) {
        packages.add(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);

        System.out.println(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
        System.out.println(resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.className);
        System.out.println(resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);
        System.out.println("");
    }

    return packages;
}
```

When I tried to list all the applications, one of them have two set listed e.g. WeChat, WeChat Moment. Obviously it have two activities which can handle the image for viewing. The problem is the name of the two are the same "WeChat".

Additionally? even though it can consume the content i passed in but they are not really application for viewing images e.g. Gallery application. Is there a way to recognise them. I know it may be impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is the name of the two are the same "WeChat".

Well, in the end, that is up to the developers of that app. However, look at `labelRes` of the `ResolveInfo`, as this may be a better label to use (e.g., pulled from the `<intent-filter>`).

> Is there a way to recognise them

You are welcome to try [using `CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY), though this may lead to false negatives (i.e., apps that the user would expect to show up that do not).

Comment: What is the different between loadLabel method and labelRes

Comment: @LittleFunny: If you mean [this `loadLabel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html#loadLabel(android.content.pm.PackageManager)), that should use `labelRes` in the `ResolveInfo`. However, `loadLabel()` on `ResolveInfo` may give more focused results than will `loadLabel()` on `ActivityInfo` or `ApplicationInfo`.

Comment: Yea i have tested the loadLabel in ResolveInfo, it returned the same as labelRes. Last question, What is relationship between ResolveInfo and ActivityInfo and ApplicationInfo. ActivityInfo = for Activity Level and ApplicationInfo = for Application Level.

Comment: @LittleFunny: `ResolveInfo` is a result for a particular `Intent` resolution (e.g., `queryIntentActivities()`). So, for example, `labelRes` on `ResolveInfo` might be pulled from the `<intent-filter>`, if the activity in question set a separate label there than on the activity itself.